# Neural Network: how to learn "Nothing"

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm working on a neural network for gesture recognition. Let's say I have four different gestures the network can distinguish. How do I design and/or train the network, that the network doesn't output a gesture if the is none or a wrong gesture, for example if the input is just the "background" without a gesture.

As I'm using the softmax function at the last layer, the network would always chose one gesture (at random?) even if there is none.

I hope my question is clear :)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This seems similar to image processing, where there are generally object detectors and object classifiers.  So you would need to design a network that detects gestures and another network that classifies them.  You could probably combine these somehow using multitask learning.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750076/what-is-the-difference-between-object-detection-and-object-classification